# Retrieve value from php file using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am just messing around with some php and jquery. My test site has the user enter in numbers in a form and then when they click submit the information is sent to that php file, does some calculations and then prints the result in a `<div>` that I specify without reloading the page. I just want to know is there any way to retrieve that value that the php file returns in a jquery variable?

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#results").hide();
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {

        },
        messages: {

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').show();
                $('#results').html(data) ;


            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you seen `$.ajax()`?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is to return response in JSON for better integration with JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP value is already being retuned as `data`.

To use it outside of your handler, assign it to a global variable.

```
var phpData = '';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#results").hide();
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {

        },
        messages: {

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data).show(); // you can chain for efficiency
                phpData = data;
            });

        }
    });
});
```

For more functionality, you can send the data from PHP as a JSON object.

```
$data = array('success' => true,
              'message' => 'Your message',
              'otherNum' => 25);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in your Javascript you can access it as follows.

```
data.success = true
data.message = 'Your message'
data.otherNum = 25
```